# Double Locking Workaround

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I want to lazily instantiate a `ViewportFactory` as follows:

```
ViewportFactory* RenderObjectFactory::GetViewportFactory() {
    if (viewportFactory == nullptr) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> instantiationLockGuard { factoryInstantiationMutex };
        if (viewportFactory == nullptr) {
            switch (GetAndCommitRenderingAPISelection()) {
                case 0:
                    ViewportFactory* v = new DirectXViewportFactory { };
                    viewportFactory = v;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return viewportFactory;
}
```

Is that sufficiently threadsafe? My thinking is that by only assigning `viewportFactory` once the `new DirectXViewportFactory` is properly instantiated, it is...

Comment: "Sufficiently threadsafe"? Either a method is threadsafe, either it is not.

Comment: Why is the viewportFactory not a static local of the function?

Comment: @DieterLücking Thread-safe initialization of local static variables was not enforced in Visual Studio until VS2013 (released November 2013). The OP may need to build with older compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as it stands is not threadsafe. The compiler is free to optimize the successive null checks since the pointer is never changed on the same thread.

I think the suggested way to do this with c++11 is with std::call_once or with a static variable.  See [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-6-double-checked-locking.html) for an example. Also: [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is safe. With optimization `viewportFactory` could still be assigned a pointer to allocated but uninitialized memory before the constructor is called. See Example 6 in [C++ and The Perils of Double-Checked Locking](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-and-the-perils-of-double-checked-locki/184405726).

Even if it were safe, this code would not be maintenance-friendly. When someone comes along later, perhaps you or perhaps someone completely unfamiliar with it, it is very easy to add code in the wrong place that would then introduce a race condition. These bugs are difficult to reproduce and isolate - is the performance gain really worth that risk?

As @DieterLücking hints, lazy instantiation can be implemented with a local static variable, which was made thread-safe in the C++11 standard. You do have to be careful that your compiler actually implements this part of the standard - for Visual Studio (since you appear to be on Windows) this did not happen until [Visual Studio 2013](http://herbsutter.com/2013/09/09/visual-studio-2013-rc-is-now-available/).